# JavaScript Audio player, need seeking on progress bar

Tags: javascript, audio, seekbar

I have some code where the progress bar is linked to the audio paying; but i haven't worked out how to seek with the mouse cursor on the progress bar. Is there a way to do this in Legacy JavaScript?

JavaScript:

```
function play() {
    document.getElementById('player').play();
}

function pause() {
    document.getElementById('player').pause();
}
function updateProgress() {
    var player = document.getElementById('player');
    var progressbar = document.getElementById('seekbar');
    progressbar.value = (player .currentTime / player .duration);
};
```

HTML:

```
<audio ontimeupdate="updateProgress()" src="music/fiji/lladep/apathy.mp3" id="player"></audio>  
<button onClick="play()">Play</button>
<button onClick="pause()">Pause</button>
<progress id="seekbar" value="0" max="1"></progress>
```

Comment: HTML5 audio tag has mouse seeking built-in.. Is it not?

Comment: Well yeah but it's quite a bit of code and you have not shown any attempt to do it

Comment: the problem is i wouldn't have a clue on where to start, as for the first comment; I'm using custom controls rather than the built in browser controls. **should i use the seeking API ?**